# Solving the LeetCode 3sum problem in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the [3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/description/) problem on LeetCode. I'm come up with the following solution:

```
import collections


class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
                d[-nums[i]-nums[j]].update(
                    {tuple(sorted([nums[i], nums[j]])): (i, j)})

        triplets = set()
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if num in d:
                for doublet, indices in d[num].items():
                    if index not in indices:
                        triplet = tuple(sorted([num, *doublet]))
                        if triplet not in triplets:
                            triplets.add(triplet)
                            break

        return [list(triplet) for triplet in triplets]
```

with the following test suite:

```
def set_equals(a, b):
    # Auxiliary method for testing
    return set(tuple(x) for x in a) == set(tuple(y) for y in b)


def test_unique():
    assert Solution().threeSum([0, 0]) == []


def test_1():
    nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 4]
    assert set_equals(
        Solution().threeSum(nums),
        [
          [-1, 0, 1],
          [-1, -1, 2]
        ])


def test_with_duplicates():
    nums = [-1, 0, -1, 0, 1]
    assert set_equals(
        Solution().threeSum(nums),
        [[-1, 0, 1]])


def test_same_number():
    assert Solution().threeSum([0, 0, 0]) == [[0, 0, 0]]


def test_3():
    assert set_equals(Solution().threeSum(
        [-4, -2, -2, -2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6]),
        [
            [-4, -2, 6],
            [-4, 0, 4],
            [-4, 1, 3],
            [-4, 2, 2],
            [-2, -2, 4],
            [-2, 0, 2]])


def test_4():
    assert set_equals(Solution().threeSum(
        [-4, -2, 1, -5, -4, -4, 4, -2, 0, 4, 0, -2, 3, 1, -5, 0]),
        [
            [-5, 1, 4],
            [-4, 0, 4],
            [-4, 1, 3],
            [-2, -2, 4],
            [-2, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]])


def test_6():
    assert set_equals(
        Solution().threeSum([0, 3, 0, 1, 1, -1, -5, -5, 3, -3, -3, 0]),
        [[-3, 0, 3], [-1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
```

All the tests pass locally:

```
$ pytest 3sum.py -s
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.8.1, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /Users/kurtpeek/GoogleDrive/LeetCode, inifile:
collected 7 items                                                              

3sum.py .......

=========================== 7 passed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
```

However, if I submit the solution on LeetCode, I get a "Wrong Answer" result:

[image]

Note, however, that this is the same test case as `test_6` in my local test suite!

Indeed if I run this input in an `ipython` shell (after renaming the file to `threesum.py` to avoid an import error), I get the expected three results, albeit in a different order:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from threesum import *

In [2]: Solution().threeSum([0, 3, 0, 1, 1, -1, -5, -5, 3, -3, -3, 0])
Out[2]: [[-1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-3, 0, 3]]
```

It seems that somehow, LeetCode's "Output" is not the same as my output. Any idea how I could get the solution to be accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran many tests as to what was happening.

This has something to do with the fact that dictionary items key, value pairs are not present in the same order in which they were pushed into the dictionary.

For example, your dictionary may have `d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}`
But when ITERATING through the dictionary:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

There is no guarantee that you get this print:

```
1, 'a'
2, 'b'
3, 'c'
```

Because dictionaries are inherently supposed to be UNORDERED.

As to why it is WORKING in YOUR machine and even MY machine is because I can venture to guess that we have Python 3.5+ (I do for sure) where the order of entry into the dictionary is being preserved.

Leetcode runs Python 3. Not 3.5+.

So when you're iterating through the dictionary

```
for doublet, indices in d[num].items():
```

Depending on the order in which `doublet, indices` appear, (THERE IS NO GUARANTEE THAT IT WILL APPEAR IN ANY SPECIFIC ORDER), you cannot guarantee that loop execution will be the same!

What can you do? I say learn to use `OrderedDict`. This preserves the order in which the key, value pair are PUT into the dictionary.

I am not an expert at `OrderedDict`, so I can't help.

But a simple print statement:

```
for doublet, indices in d[num].items():
    print(doublet, indices)
```

in both your own local machine and in your Leetcode output will show you what I mean.. Printing `doublet, indices` makes them show up in different order in your Leetcode output and in your local machine output.

Comment: From the wording of the example on LeetCode, "A solution set is:", it would seem that the order of the output does not matter, which is what I tried to emulate using the `set_equal` auxiliary function. Further, even if the order did matter, LeetCode is reporting for my code's output a result, `[[-1, 0, 1], [-3, 0, 3]]`, which does not include the `[0, 0, 0]` result, which my code does generate as seen from the 'local' tests. So why is an entire result missing only on LeetCode?

Comment: I see `Expected output` to include `[0, 0, 0]` as posted in your picture. It is only OUR output generated from our code that does not include `[0, 0, 0]`, the reasoning for which I have given saying that depending on the order in which the key, value pairs are seen in the dictionary, computation proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

At the heart of the problem is the `break` statement which introduces the 'order dependency' explain by [Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7938658/abhishek). If I comment out the `break` statement, I get a different error, `Time Limit Exceeded`:

[image]

Apparently, my O(N^2) solution is too slow, but at least it is now giving the correct answers.